# find the count of substring in string

Tags: c, string, search, substring

I have to find the count of a substring in a string using the C language.
I'm using the function [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) but it only finds the first occurrence.

My idea of the algorithm is something like searching in the string while `strstr` does not return null and 
to substring the main string on each loop.
My question is how to do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could do something like

```
int countString(const char *haystack, const char *needle){
    int count = 0;
    const char *tmp = haystack;
    while(tmp = strstr(tmp, needle))
    {
        count++;
        tmp++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

That is, when you get a result, start searching again at the next position of the string.

strstr() doesn't only work starting from the beginning of a string but from any position.

Comment: If they need to be distinct substrings, you might consider `count+=strlen(string2find)`

Comment: Edit, I added protection against problems in case of string2find=""

Comment: @Dave, beware of infinite loop for ""

Comment: @Dave and future readers, I believe you meant `tmp += strlen(string2find)`. In your example, you are incrementing the number of occurrences by the length of the string!

Comment: if you are finding "zz" in "zzzz" it would return 3 and (with tmp++) I believe this is correct answer, if you do something like tmp += strlen(string2find) this would just return with 2.

Answer (score 6):

Should already processed parts of the string should be consumed or not?

For example, what's the expect answer for case of searching `oo` in `foooo`, **2 or 3**?

- If the latter (we **allow substring overlapping**, and the answer is three), then Joachim Isaksson [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9052540/545027) the right code.
- If we **search for distinct substrings** (the answer should be two), then see the code below (and online example [here](https://ideone.com/2xV4YR)):

  ```
  char *str = "This is a simple string";
  char *what = "is";

  int what_len = strlen(what);
  int count = 0;

  char *where = str;

  if (what_len) 
      while ((where = strstr(where, what))) {
          where += what_len;
          count++;
      }
  ```

Answer (score 6):

USE [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) and you can do it in O(n)

```
int fail[LEN+1];
char s[LEN];
void getfail()
{
    //f[i+1]= max({j|s[i-j+1,i]=s[0,j-1],j!=i+1})
    //the correctness can be proved by induction
    for(int i=0,j=fail[0]=-1;s[i];i++)
    {
        while(j>=0&&s[j]!=s[i]) j=fail[j];
        fail[i+1]=++j;
        if (s[i+1]==s[fail[i+1]]) fail[i+1]=fail[fail[i+1]];//optimizing fail[]
    }
}

int kmp(char *t)// String s is pattern and String t is text!
{
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0,j=0;t.s[i];i++)
    {
        while(j>=0&&t.s[i]!=s[j]) j=fail[j];
        if (!s[++j])
        {
            j=fail[j];
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;// how many times s appeared in t.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The results can be different depending whether you allow an overlap or not:

```
// gcc -std=c99
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int
count_substr(const char *str, const char* substr, bool overlap) {
  if (strlen(substr) == 0) return -1; // forbid empty substr

  int count = 0;
  int increment = overlap ? 1 : strlen(substr);
  for (char* s = (char*)str; (s = strstr(s, substr)); s += increment)
    ++count;
  return count;
}

int main() {
  char *substrs[] = {"a", "aa", "aaa", "b", "", NULL };
  for (char** s = substrs; *s != NULL; ++s)
    printf("'%s' ->  %d, no overlap: %d\n", *s, count_substr("aaaaa", *s, true),
       count_substr("aaaaa", *s, false));
}
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/TVkGM)

```
'a' ->  5, no overlap: 5
'aa' ->  4, no overlap: 2
'aaa' ->  3, no overlap: 1
'b' ->  0, no overlap: 0
'' ->  -1, no overlap: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `s` and `substr` are non-null and non-empty:

```
/* #times substr appears in s, no overlaps */
int nappear(const char *s, const char *substr)
{
    int n = 0;
    const char *p = s;

    size_t lenSubstr = strlen(substr);

    while (*p) {
        if (memcmp(p, substr, lenSubstr) == 0) {
            ++n;
            p += lenSubstr;
        } else 
            ++p;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/* 
 * C Program To Count the Occurence of a Substring in String 
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char str[100], sub[100];
int count = 0, count1 = 0;

void main()
{
    int i, j, l, l1, l2;

    printf("\nEnter a string : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);

    l1 = strlen(str);

    printf("\nEnter a substring : ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", sub);

    l2 = strlen(sub);

    for (i = 0; i < l1;)
    {
        j = 0;
        count = 0;
        while ((str[i] == sub[j]))
        {
            count++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (count == l2)
        {
            count1++;                                   
            count = 0;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }    
    printf("%s occurs %d times in %s", sub, count1, str);
}
```

Comment: Don't use global variables for no reason. `void main` is wrong; should be `int main`. `"%[^\n]s"` doesn't do what you want; the `s` is not part of the `%` directive and requires a literal `s` to be entered. You didn't specify an upper bound for inputs; this is a potential buffer overflow. Always check the return value of `scanf` if you have to use it. Don't use `scanf` for user input. `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`. You have redundant parentheses in the `while` condition; while not a bug per se, this silences the warning gcc would give you if you typo'd `==` as `=`.

Comment: The `while` loop doesn't check for end-of-string and can run off the end of `str` and `sub` if all characters match. `j` and `count` are always set together; they're effectively the same variable. Your algorithm is completely broken: It doesn't find e.g. `"ab"` in `"aab"`.

Comment: In general, avoid posting answers that consist of code only. A description of the algorithm or an explanation of how your answer is different from the others would help.